# Java Generics Compiler Error in Chain of Responsibility design principle

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
public abstract class AbstractExecutor<PARAM, RET> {

private AbstractExecutor<?, ?> nextExecutor;
    
public abstract RET execute(PARAM param);

public void executeAll(PARAM par) {
    System.out.println("Executing..");
    RET ret= execute(par);
     if(this.nextExecutor!=null){
         System.out.println("Executing.." + this.getClass());
            this.nextExecutor.executeAll(ret);
        }
}

public AbstractExecutor<?, ?> setNextExecutor(AbstractExecutor<?,?> next){
    this.nextExecutor = next;
    return this.nextExecutor;
}}
```

Can anyone help me with this code, why I am wrong here "this.nextExecutor.executeAll(ret);" ? I am getting
"The method executeAll(capture#4-of ?) in the type AbstractExecutor<capture#4-of ?,capture#5-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (RET)"
but unable to understand whats wrong here?
How to correct this ?

Comment: `private AbstractExecutor<?, ?> nextExecutor;` Replace the first `?` with `PARAM` and the second `?` with `RET`. Refer to [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) lesson in Oracle's Java tutorials. Also [Understanding Java generics, Part 1: Principles and fundamentals](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/understanding-java-generics-part-1-principles-and-fundamentals) and also [Generics guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html) from JDK documentation.

Comment: By the way, your question title has nothing to do with your problem. Your code simply does not compile. Maybe change the question title to something like: _Java Generics Compiler Error_ Better yet, try [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+generics+compiler+error) for those words.

Comment: Thanks @Abra updated the title. But issue doesn't resolve with the change you suggested.

Comment: The `this.nextExecutor.executeAll` parameter is of type `?`, which could be anything. You pass an argument of type `RET`, so the compiler doesn't know if the argument is right. Your `AbstractExecutor<?, ?> nextExecutor` should be `AbstractExecutor<RET, ?> nextExecutor`.

Comment: You edited the question and added more code after I posted my first comment so obviously the _issue doesn't resolve with the change ... suggested_ I also get the impression that you didn't read the links in my comments. I recommend that you read those links first.

Comment: Thanks @akuzminykh It worked, So Is my implementation is good, or it has issue with design constraints ? I have to deal with heterogeneous data, but next executor definitely will be executing the return value of previous one.

Comment: @Abra I am reading those links, Thanks @Abra!!

Comment: @AnshulKhandelwal What you do here can be done more elegantly by chaining `CompletableFuture`s. I can't tell for sure, as I don't know anything else than your snippet.

Comment: Thanks @akuzminykh, I got you!! Will update the code thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `PARAM` and `RET` are [type] parameters, i.e. they are not actual types.

Method `executeAll` is essentially a recursive method, i.e. it calls itself and the value returned from method `execute` serves as the argument for [the recursive invocation of] method `executeAll`. Hence RET must either be the same as PARAM or a subset of it. Therefore, the following code does compile.

```java
public abstract class AbstractExecutor<PARAM, RET extends PARAM> {
    private AbstractExecutor<PARAM, RET> nextExecutor;

    public abstract RET execute(PARAM param);

    public void executeAll(PARAM par) {
        System.out.println("Executing..");
        RET ret = execute(par);
        if (this.nextExecutor != null) {
            System.out.println("Executing.." + this.getClass());
            this.nextExecutor.executeAll(ret);
        }
    }

    public AbstractExecutor<PARAM, RET> setNextExecutor(AbstractExecutor<PARAM, RET> next) {
        this.nextExecutor = next;
        return this.nextExecutor;
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution works too. Only thing here is RET data have no linking with PARAM data, both are independent of each other, which breaks my Implementation of this abstract class. Thanks for sharing the alternative approach.